# Hibernate batch insert a list into a table which has unique column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I hava a list contains 1,000,000 records.

I want to insert the list into a table which already have 5,000,000 records.

The code:

```
Sample s = null;
for(int i=0,len=list.size();i<list;i++){
  s = new Sample();
  session.save(s);
  if(i%20==0){
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
  }
}
```

A column in this table is unique column.

Some records in this list is same to records in this table.

like this:

list : ['a','b','c']...

table : ['a','d','e']...

'a' is duplicate, so this code can't word well.

Exception: `don't flush the Session after an exception occurs`

It's too sloooooooooooow to use this:

```
String sql = 'insert ignore into xxxxx';
session.createSqlQuery().executeUpdate();
```

How should I do? Help me, please~~~

Comment: did you tried to drop `unique` constraints in your db?

Comment: @Rafik991 Yes. I dropped unique constraints in my db, and check each code before use.Thanks.